# Cases of information stolen by eavesdropping due to non-use of TLS

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

Have there been any actual known examples of widespread (or not) information e.g. passwords or credit card details lost to an eavesdropper or MITM due to non-use of SSL/TLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does anecdotal evidence count? Many, many people have done this before. One (comical) example is the DEF CON "Wall of Sheep", where the network at the DEF CON security event logs all plaintext logins and posts the information up on a public display. I even recall seeing a guy walking around with a hat covered in a PCB that had a tiny screen on his forehead, displaying in real-time the passwords that people were using over non-secured connections.

Another example is for proxies. It is not at all uncommon for public proxies to sniff for logins. Some such proxies are so blatant that they keep the "mitmproxy" header there, giving away that they are using software specifically designed for this purpose. Occasionally, people also see Tor exit nodes set up by malicious parties which try to steal information from people who are foolishly attempting to submit sensitive credentials over an insecure connection.

People stealing credentials over public, insecure Wi-Fi (at cafés, hotels, or airports, for example) is also a ubiquitous issue. I have seen people attempt this in real-time, and I have done it myself as well (not to steal credentials, but to obtain information on a specific target). There are also countless script kiddies who go to public hotspots (or break weak encrypted Wi-Fi) and simply perform a complete dump of all traffic going through the network for later analysis.

Comment: Ah, right, I can't believe I forgot about that. I kept thinking of eavesdropping over the internet instead of just on a local network.

Comment: Usually it's done over a local network. Doing it over the internet would be the situation that occurs with a malicious proxy, though particularly advanced attackers can attack from other locations.

Answer (score 1):

[Firesheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) was a Firefox extension that enabled trivial interception and use of session cookies transmitted over plain-text HTTP connections (from the days when people thought that making only the login form use HTTPS was OK). It may be the most widespread tool for this kind of thing, and shortly after it was released, all the major online services switched to using constant HTTPS for all authenticated traffic.